# Does VueJS production mode remove all warning

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Inside VueJS deployment doc, they say that in production mode warnings are not displayed

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html

> However, these warning strings become useless in production and bloat your app’s payload size

Does every warning are not displayed anymore or some of this warnings can't still be there, especially compilation error ?

It seems weird that compilations errors displayed in vue warning on dev mode cannot be seen in prod mode.

Furthermore compilation error can break other non VueJS scripts.

Comment: Errors and warnings are not the same thing.  Errors will continue to display in production mode, as always.  Vue's development warnings will not.

Comment: Yea, so this is weird that `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:` is an error displayed with `Vue warn` before.

Comment: That is a Vue development warning, so, yes, it will be removed from the production build. The assumption is that you've fixed such errors before going to production!